# Deploy a Meteor iOS application

Tags: ios, meteor, meteor-ios

I followed instruction.

```
meteor deploy subdomain.meteor.com

meteor build ~/directory/ --server=subdomain.meteor.com
```

However, the iOS app didn't work well on Simulator and iOS devices. I figured out that those methods that running from Server side didn't get called. If I tried to move out those methods to the client-side, functions can run again. 
However, when I developed this app, I didn't realize such an issue, so I already wrote a lot of methods in the backend. It will be time-consuming to move all the backend code to the client-side, and it's not logical either.

If I tried 
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=subdomain.meteor.com:3000, it works ok on Simulator, but not ok on physical devices. I realize that this issue is because my localhost:3000 is somehow running.

Can someone please instruct me how to make my app point to Meteor server successfully?

I believe I need to reconfigure the access-origin stuff. Can anyone give me instruction for re-configure Access-Origin?

Comment: it's really not clear what you are asking, or what you mean by "configuring access-origin". Why are yo trying to access the app on port 3000? After you deploy to meteor.com it will run on port 80 as it should.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I deployed to meteor.com. If I type "meteor build ~/directory/ --server=subdomain.meteor.com" the iOS app cannot run "server code", only the "client side codes" can run. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To allow the access origin in Cordova, add this line in your mobile.config.js

```
App.accessRule('subdomain.meteor.com/*')
```

And do the same for any resources with external domains required in your app, or wildcard it like this (not really recommended)

```
App.accessRule('*');
```